# How to do a basic cross page test ? Login example

Tags: extjs, siesta

So I'm testing my login page with this piece of code

```
describe('Testing the login page', function (t) {
    t.it('Should be possible to login', function (t) {
        t.chain(
            {
                waitForCQ : '>> textfield[itemId=login]'
            },
            {
                action  : 'type',
                target  : '>> textfield[itemId=login]',
                text    : 'accountname'
             },
            {
                action  : 'type',
                target  : '>> textfield[itemId=password]',
                text    : 'passwd[ENTER]'
             }
        )
    })
});
```

with this harness.start() conf :

```
harness.start(
  '010_sanity.t.js',
  {
    group   : 'Login/Logout',
    items   : [
      {
        enablePageRedirect : true,
        pageUrl : "https://mywebsite.com/Login",
        url     : "020_login.t.js"
      },
      {
        enablePageRedirect : true,
        pageUrl : "https://mywebsite.com/",
        url     : "021_logout.t.js"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
);
```

And I'm facing a problem. Even with the enablePageRedirect option set to true, tests don't seem to persist from the first page to the next one.
In contrary, in the logging area of the siesta test interface (middle one), I see the test restarting from scratch when the page has changed.
With a never ending spinner.

How to do such a simple cross page test with siesta ? 
The doc hasn't really helped me : http://www.bryntum.com/docs/siesta/#!/guide/cross_page_testing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each test is expected to start from a fresh page and be self-contained, so each of your tests would need to begin by logging into the app freshly. Enabling page redirect simply means that once the login occurs, the app can continue being tested after reaching the next page. Here's an example of how we write it in our tests:

```
  test.chain(
    // Enter username
    {
      action: 'type',
      target: '#user_id',
      text: 'ACCOUNTNAMEHERE'
    },
    // Enter password
    {
      action: 'type',
      target: '#password',
      text: 'PASSWORDHERE'
    },
    // Set up detection of the page changing.
    // The trigger specifies what action will cause the
    // page to change. The timeout is the maximum length
    // to wait for the navigation to occur.
    {
      waitFor: 'PageLoad',
      timeout: 20000,
      trigger: {
        click: 'input[type=submit]'
      }
    }
  );
```